# Realizando consultas mysql

Tags: mysql

Estoy haciendo una aplicación donde un usuario realiza una orden con varios productos, para eso creé 4 tablas users, orders, products_per_order, products tal como se ve el diagrama y en las tablas.

Ahora quiero hacer el query para seleccionar, el nickname, el name lastname, las ordenes que hizo ese usuario y los productos de esa orden, hice este query

pero obtengo este error:

> La selección actual no contiene una columna única. La edición de la
> grilla y los enlaces de copiado, eliminación y edición no están
> disponibles

y solo trae nick name_lastname

como podria traer la info requerida?

Gracias por la ayuda

```
SELECT users.user_nick, users.name_last_name FROM users 
JOIN orders ON users.user_id = orders.user_id
JOIN products_per_order ON products_per_order.id_order = orders.id_order
JOIN products ON products.product_id = products_per_order.product_id
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   user_id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   user varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
   name_last_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   phone_number int NOT NULL,
   direction varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   rol varchar(11)  DEFAULT 'user'               
);



CREATE TABLE Orders (
   id_order int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   user_id  int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE products (
   product_id int PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   product_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   quantity int NOT NULL
   
);


CREATE TABLE products_per_order (
   products_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   id_order int NOT NULL,
   product_id int NOT NULL
);




ALTER TABLE orders ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user_id FOREIGN KEY(user_id)
REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE products_per_order ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id_order FOREIGN KEY(id_order)
REFERENCES orders(id_order) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE products_per_order ADD CONSTRAINT fk_product_id FOREIGN KEY(product_id)
REFERENCES products(product_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: ¿Puedes subir la estructura de la BD donde se muestran las PK y FK?

Comment: Hola, si están en el diagrama

Comment: y  añadí  el código de creación de las tablas abajo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replique tu codigo y encontre un par de errores al momento de crear tu base de datos, recuerda que los datos deben ser explicitos, tambien si puedes normaliza la base de datos minimo hasta tercer forma normal.

El error presentado es por que tus llaves foraneas estan mal creadas, por ello tras modificarlo queda el siguiente codigo y semanticamente la consulta que hiciste esta bien

```
SELECT users.user_nick, users.name_last_name FROM users 
JOIN orders ON users.user_id = orders.user_id
JOIN products_per_order ON products_per_order.id_order = orders.id_order
JOIN products ON products.product_id = products_per_order.product_id
```

Te anexo el codigo completo de la BD correspondiente, si llega a fallar dimelo y con gusto actualizo

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orders`;
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id_order` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hour` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `payment` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_order`),
  KEY `fk_user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products`;

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products_per_order`;
CREATE TABLE `products_per_order` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`),
  KEY `fk_id_order` (`id_order`),
  KEY `fk_product_id` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_id_order` FOREIGN KEY (`id_order`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id_order`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`product_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_nick` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `name_last_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `direction` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `rol` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

### Edicion

Para evitar errores en las llaves foraneas primero se deben crear las tablas independientes y luego las dependientes

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_nick` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `name_last_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `direction` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `rol` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orders`;
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id_order` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hour` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `payment` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_order`),
  KEY `fk_user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products`;

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products_per_order`;
CREATE TABLE `products_per_order` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`),
  KEY `fk_id_order` (`id_order`),
  KEY `fk_product_id` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_id_order` FOREIGN KEY (`id_order`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id_order`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`product_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Hola , aparece este error, pero no se porque mis foreign key estan mal? a mi modo de ver están iguales, solo que los agregué despues de crear las tablas,..............#1005 - No puedo crear tabla `test`.`orders` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: MySQL es muy especial en la forma que creas elementos, debes revisar que esten escritas de la misma manera, que tengan el mismo tipo de dato y longitud o como en el caso del error que te aparece que exista la referencia, para el error que te aparece debes crear primero la tabla `users` ya que si te das cuenta la tabla `orders` hace referencia a esta.